# Complex MongoDB syntax in Linux Shell script

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell

I have created a CRON job that takes backup of database everyday.

The script has a command of Mongodump with a condition to dump the records that are 7 days old.

The script runs fine until I added the `--query` parameter into the `mongodump` command.

```
mongodump [host, port and dbparams] --query "{_id: {\$lt: ObjectId(Math.floor(new Date(Date.now() - 86400000*7)/1000).toString(16) + '0000000000000000')}}"
```

An error thrown because of the `--query`, which says:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting quoted string: offset:21
```

So what is the correct way to integrate this query into the script?

Comment: Does using `'$lt'` instead of `\$lt` help?

Comment: @OneOfOne Nope, the `'$lt'` without `'\'` gives error `'First character in field must be [A-Za-z$_]: offset:7'`. I have added `'\'` to escape the `$` .

Comment: @sohelkhalifa can we run the scripts without having mongo shell installed in machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute the date string using the shell and then pass that into the --query option. Here is your original Javascript expression and the equivalent computation in the shell:

```
$ mongo --eval "Math.floor(new Date(Date.now() - 86400000*7)/1000).toString(16) + '0000000000000000'"
526a7ac00000000000000000
$ printf '%x0000000000000000' $(($(date +%s) - 86400*7))
526a7ac00000000000000000
```

You would then use this in a short script such as the following:

```
now=$(printf '%x0000000000000000' $(($(date +%s) - 86400*7)))
mongodump --query "{_id: {\$lt: '$now'}}"
```

Hope this helps,

Bruce

Comment: Bruce's solution, a little simpler: `printf '%x0000000000000000' $(date --date='7 days ago' +%s)`

Comment: Good improvement Rafa.